# How to programmatically send text message notifications without knowing provider?

Tags: mobile, sms

Many banks, airlines, etc. offer the possibility to receive text message notifications by entering your mobile number. Some other sites have you enter your mobile number and wireless carrier and send messages to your free per-provider email-to-mobile number. But some people definitely do it without asking for the provider. How is this accomplished? Are there commercial services that provide this functionality?

(if this doesn't belong on SO, feel free to migrate to another SE site)

**Edit:** I'm primarily concerned with mobile numbers in the US, but interested in answers for other countries as well.

Comment: Which country are you referring to?  This varies by country and provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, providers of this service are called SMS gateways, good ones should be able to set you up with an API for bi-directional use

Comment: Check out Twilio as an example of one built for web developers specifically. I work there and can answer any questions you have.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways this can happen. If you have access to cellular hardware, like Multitech's MTC-H5 cellular modem or their rCell 100 cellular gateway, you're sending SMS just like a cell phone does, so this bypasses the need to know the carrier of the phone number. If the program you're using can't directly access the hardware, you could try to use a program like ours, PageGate, to receiving alerting notifications from that program to interface with the hardware to deliver the SMS.

There are also message aggregators, companies who provide a web API that allows you to send SMS. You submit the phone number with message to their API, they handle the delivery. Examples of these companies would be Infobip and Clickatell or if you're looking for something for medical markets, you could try TigerText, or for emergency management, you could try Active911 or I Am Responding.